# Membership with Facebook (Error: MySql)

Tags: php, mysql

Facebook and Twitter membership script error:
(does not record data to the database)

Login=>FB/TW DATABASE=>**CONNECT OK!**=>BACK TO MY WEBSITE=>MY DATABASE=>ERROR

**SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
email VARCHAR(70),
oauth_uid VARCHAR(200),
oauth_provider VARCHAR(200),
username VARCHAR(100),
twitter_oauth_token VARCHAR(200),
twitter_oauth_token_secret VARCHAR(200)
);
```

**loginFacebook.php:**

```
<?php
require 'dbconfig.php';
class User {

function checkUser($uid, $oauth_provider, $username,$email,$twitter_otoken,$twitter_otoken_secret) 
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE oauth_uid = '$uid' and oauth_provider = '$oauth_provider'") or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    if (!empty($result)) {
        # User is already present
    } else {
        #user not present. Insert a new Record
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, username,email,twitter_oauth_token,twitter_oauth_token_secret) VALUES ('$oauth_provider', $uid, '$username','$email')") or die(mysql_error());
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE oauth_uid = '$uid' and oauth_provider = '$oauth_provider'");
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        return $result;
    }
    return $result;
}
} ?>
```

**Screen: Error**

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

What's wrong?

best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is

```
INSERT INTO `users` (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, username, email, twitter_oauth_token, twitter_oauth_token_secret) 
VALUES ('$oauth_provider', $uid, '$username','$email')")
```

As you see you are trying to insert `6` values, however in query you are providing data of only 4 items `('$oauth_provider', $uid, '$username','$email')`, it is showing error.

Below are two ways use you can use depending on the requirement you have.

**Option 1**

```
INSERT INTO `users` (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, username, email, twitter_oauth_token, twitter_oauth_token_secret) 
VALUES ('$oauth_provider', $uid, '$username','$email',NULL, NULL)")
```

OR **Option 2**

```
INSERT INTO `users` (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, username, email)
VALUES ('$oauth_provider', $uid, '$username','$email')")
```

Comment: Works now! Fahim, Thank you for help & interest!

Answer (score 2):

Reformatted your query to be on multiple lines for readability:

```
$query = mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO `users`
    (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, username, email, twitter_oauth_token, twitter_oauth_token_secret)
    VALUES
        ('$oauth_provider', $uid, '$username','$email')
    "
) or die(mysql_error());
```

You are specifying 6 columns in your `INSERT` statement, but only supplying 4 actual values for these columns. Either remove the last 2 `twitter_oauth_*` columns from your query, or supply the values for these columns.